# Adding Commands to my Buttons

Tags: c#, button, visual-studio-2013, command

I just created some buttons for the IDE Toolbar.

But right now how do I fill them with some functions like opening a new window or counting numbers?

Here is my ISIPlusToolbar.vcst data.

```
    <Button guid="guidISIPlusToolbarCmdSet" id="cmdidOptions" priority="0x0101" type="Button">
    <Parent guid="guidISIPlusToolbarCmdSet" id="ISIPlusToolbarGroup" />
    <Icon guid="guidImages" id="bmpPic1" />
    <CommandFlag>TextChanges</CommandFlag>
    <Strings>
      <CommandName>cmdidOptions</CommandName>
      <ButtonText>Options</ButtonText>
    </Strings>
  </Button>

  <Button guid="guidISIPlusToolbarCmdSet" id="cmdidNSLManager" priority="0x0101" type="Button">
    <Parent guid="guidISIPlusToolbarCmdSet" id="ISIPlusToolbarGroup" />
    <Icon guid="guidImages" id="bmpPic2" />
    <CommandFlag>TextChanges</CommandFlag>
    <Strings>
      <CommandName>cmdidNSLManager</CommandName>
      <ButtonText>NSL Manager</ButtonText>
    </Strings>
  </Button>

  <Button guid="guidISIPlusToolbarCmdSet" id="cmdidIconPicker" priority="0x0101" type="Button">
    <Parent guid="guidISIPlusToolbarCmdSet" id="ISIPlusToolbarGroup" />
    <Icon guid="guidImages" id="bmpPicX" />
    <CommandFlag>TextChanges</CommandFlag>
    <Strings>
      <CommandName>cmdidIconPicker</CommandName>
      <ButtonText>Icon Picker</ButtonText>
    </Strings>
  </Button>
```

And this is my Package.cs where I already tried to get at least one of these buttons going but It's not working and I don't know why.

```
      protected override void Initialize()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine (string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Entering Initialize() of: {0}", this.ToString()));
        base.Initialize();

        // Add our command handlers for menu (commands must exist in the .vsct file)
        OleMenuCommandService mcs = GetService(typeof(IMenuCommandService)) as OleMenuCommandService;
        if ( null != mcs )
        {
            // Create the command for the menu item.
            CommandID menuCommandID = new CommandID(GuidList.guidISIPlusToolbarCmdSet, (int)PkgCmdIDList.cmdidISIPlusToolbar);
            OleMenuCommand menuItem = new OleMenuCommand(MenuItemCallback, menuCommandID );
            menuItem.BeforeQueryStatus +=
                new EventHandler(OnBeforeQueryStatus);
            mcs.AddCommand( menuItem );
        }
    }
    #endregion


    private void OnBeforeQueryStatus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int counter = 1;
        var myCommand = sender as OleMenuCommand;
        if (null != myCommand)
        {
            counter++;
            Console.WriteLine(counter);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: See [questions seeking debugging help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: See https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Menu-and-commands-VS-2013-71c62827